# Como validar si existe un dato en la Bd para realizar una consulta usando Java?

Tags: java, spring, condiciones, nullpointerexception

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual hace una consulta a bd a través de un parámetro (folio) y al regresar la informacion de ese folio se realizan validaciones, el problema es que si yo le mando un folio incorrecto que no esta en la bd, me truena por null, como puedo validar para que no truene y que me regre un mensaje de ese dato no existe en la bd o algo asi

```html
public DatosSalida consulta(DatosaEntrada body){

 DatosSalida salida = new DatosSalida();
 try{
  salida = service.consultarDatos(body);
  
 
 }catch(Exception e){
  salida = new DatosSalida();
  salida.setDiagnostico("01");
 }
 
 return salida;
}



public DatosSalida consultarDatos(DatosaEntrada entrada){
 DatosSalida salida = new DatosSalida();
 
 InformacionAceptada  infAcept = InformacionRepository.buscaFolio(entrada.getFolio());
 
 if(!entrada.getCurpValido.equals(infoAcept.getCurp())){
  salida.serResultado("Rechazo")
  salida.setValidacion("02");
 }else if(entrada.getTipoTrabajador != 1){
  salida.serResultado("Rechazo")
  salida.setValidacion("02");
 }else{
  salida.serResultado("Aceptado")
  salida.setValidacion("01");
  salida.setDatoVerificador(1);
 
 }
 

 return salida;
}
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: ¿Qué te parece una comprobación si `infAcept != null` antes de hacer cualquier cosa? Además, si tienes errores muestra la salida del error

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev gracias, si funciono